# Why is the content of a Receipt for New Memberships different to that for a Renewed Membership

Tags: civimember

There is a key data element that is missing from the Renewal receipt. "Financial Type" is present in a receipt for a new Membership but is NOT shown in the receipt for a renewed Membership.

We use Financial Type to differentiate between Member Subscriptions and Annual Donations / Sponsorships. For Tax purposes, the word Donation in the receipt is key for a donor to claim a partial refund.

So the issue is can the Financial Type element be made available for a renewal receipt. Alternatively is there a suggested work around that can be inserted in the HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

The receipt templates are at Mailings > Message Templates > System Workflow Messages

Under Memberships, there are two receipt templates for on-line and off-line.  From a quick look at those, I'm not clear how your problem arises.

What version are you on?  Templates do get changed so your problem may already have been fixed in later versions.

Are you using the default versions?  If not, it will show you a 'Revert to Default' and 'View Default' menu link as well as 'Edit'.  If changes were made to your templates a while ago then they may be very different to the current default version.  In this case, you need to compare your customised version with the default version.

If you are on the default version then you can easily experiment with some changes and use the 'Revert to Default' if you mess up.  Otherwise, you can save a copy somewhere, try changes and copy back your original saved version.

Hopefully that gives you enough to get started and narrow down the issue to a specific template and area of the file.  If you update your question with more detail someone can help you further.

Comment: TX. I am familiar with the Receipt options (offline / online) and have made changes to the HTML script - in particular some of the wording in the offline version to suit our situation regarding Donations. In the HTML script it refers to sign-ups and renewals:
{if $formValues.receipt_text_signup}
     <p>{$formValues.receipt_text_signup|htmlize}</p>
    {elseif $formValues.receipt_text_renewal}
     <p>{$formValues.receipt_text_renewal|htmlize}</p>
It would seem that the Financial Type element is not part of the formvalues for renewals, as I cannot get it to print for a renewal receipt.